# Batch file on Server 2008

Tags: batch-file

I have a scheduled task that calls a simple .bat file to check if a program is running and start it if not. The .bat file is simply:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myprog.exe" | find /i "myprog.exe" 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 start "" myprog.exe "myprog_parms.ini"
```

If I run this from the desktop, myprog.exe starts fine in a new window however when run as a scheduled task, myprog.exe gets started but not in a window - all I can see is it as a process under the Task Manager.

I'm guessing that I'm missing something simple here but would appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you schedule the task? Do you have the "hidden" tick on?

Comment: I created a Task in thhe Task Scheduler and the Hidden box is not ticked.

Comment: What user is it running as?

Comment: Task is running as Admin user

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, a local admin user that has rights to run the program

Comment: Tried start "" /i myprog.exe "myprog_parms.ini"
but still not displaying the running program in a new window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible anymore: services are run on a different desktop than users, and this affects the Task Scheduler as well.

More info-  http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation.aspx